# Raft crashing, please help

Tags: technical-issues, raft

I bought Raft on steam earlier today, and it seems to crash every time I start it.

It passes the Published by and Developed by screen, then it just hangs on the background for about 3 seconds before it closes.
My graphics card is Intel Graphics 620 and it seems to be around the same as the system requirements.
And to add on top of that, multiple people with worse systems than me seem to run it fine.

Comment: Have you verified game files?

Comment: I have verified them.

Comment: Graphics are not the only key component for a game. Do you have the minimum CPU and RAM?

Comment: I have an Intel i7-7500u @ 2.70GHz with 8GB ram.

Comment: Does anything appear in the Windows Event Viewer upon crashing?

Comment: I'll check in a second. I'm making something ATM but when I'm done I'll check.

Comment: Sorry to annoy you, but how do I do that? I know how to open the Event Viewer. But where shall I go from here? Thanks :)

Comment: @EliteUnity - Your best bet is to start the game, wait for it to crash, then go look for recent crash logs under Windows Logs -> Application.